# coordinate location based off pixel color

Tags: python, opencv, colors, coordinates

I am trying to get specific coordinates in an image.  I have marked a red dot in the image at several locations to specify the coordinates I want to get.  In GIMP I used the purist red I could find (HTML notation **ff000**).  The idea was that I would iterate through the image until I found a pure shade of red and then print out the coordinates.  I am using python and opencv to do so but I can't find any good tutorials (best I could find is [this](http://opencv-python-tutroals.readthedocs.io/en/latest/py_tutorials/py_core/py_basic_ops/py_basic_ops.html) but it's not very clear...at least for me).  Here is an example of the image I am dealing with.[image]
I just want to know how to find the coordinates of the pixels with the red dots.

EDIT (added code):

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

img = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
width, height = img.shape[:2]
for i in range(0,width):
   for j in range(0,height):
      px = img[i,j]
```

I don't know what to do from here.  I have tried code such as `if px == [x,y,z]` looking for color detection but that doesn't work.

Comment: have you tried any code yet? if yes, please post it too

Comment: Search for *blob detection using opencv* or *color segmentation using opencv*

Comment: If it  is just the red colors, try inRange from OpenCV and then find non zero values...

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with cv2 this way:

```
image = cv2.imread('image.jpg')
lower_red = np.array([0,0,220])  # BGR-code of your lowest red
upper_red = np.array([10,10,255])   # BGR-code of your highest red 
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower_red, upper_red)  
#get all non zero values
coord=cv2.findNonZero(mask)
```

Comment: `#get all non zero values
coord=cv2.findNonZero(mask)` this one was on point! Thank you

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with PIL and numpy.  I'm sure there is a similar implementation with cv2.

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np

img = Image.open('image.png')

width, height = img.size[:2]
px = np.array(img)

for i in range(height):
   for j in range(width):
      if(px[i,j,0] == 255 & px[i,j,1] == 0 & px[i,j,2] == 0):
          print(i,j,px[i,j])
```

This doesn't work with the image you provided, since there aren't any pixels that are exactly (255,0,0).  Something may have changed when it got compressed to a .jpg, or you didn't make them as red as you thought you did.  Perhaps you could try turning off anti-aliasing in GIMP.

Comment: I decided to check up on your theory that the pixel color might be off.  I printed out all the pixels around one of the dots (wid 300 - 400 len: 100-200).  Turns out you where right no value was pure 255 red.  For all output of pixel color [r,g,b] no value was above 50.  This is weird considering while the value may not be 255 for red it should still be higher than 50 on the red spot.  Any ideas?